# Install new package version using old nuget (vs 2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I am in kind of situation where i need to use newer packages which is not supported by nuget in visual studio 2012. Is there a way to install a newer version package with/without nuget? Whats the downside?